# Dynamically update two JSF PrimeFaces Listboxes

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listbox

I am creating a web application using JSF Primeface on Netbeans. What I'm trying to do is dynamically update two selectOneListBox items. To be more specific, I want to update the values on the second listbox based on the value I click on the first listbox.

For example: I have two databases, Activities and Subactivities, and I want to display them on separate listboxes. Activities could have "Music, Sports, Outdoor, Indoor, etc". I want to display these values on the first listbox. When I click on one of them, I want to get the subactivities associated with the specific activity. So in the subcategory database, there is a list of sub activities each with a unique identifier associated with a member form the activity database. When I click on an entry on the activity listbox, I want to pull the specific subactivities and display them on the second listbox.

I was able to get the values from the activities database and display them on the first listbox:

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{activityController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{activityController.items}" var="item"
        itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.activityName}"/>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

How would I got about implementing the second listbox?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Your First selectOneListbox:

```
<h:form>
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{activityController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" id="listBox1">
   <f:selectItems value="#{activityController.items}" var="item"
    itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.activityName}"/>
   <p:ajax listener="#{activityController.itemChange}"
                            update="listBox2" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

Second:

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{activityController.subItem}" id="listBox2">
   <f:selectItems value="#{activityController.subItems}" var="item"
    itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.activityName}"/>       
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

Backing Bean:

```
public void itemChange() {
 // load stuff based on selected item
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I send the item clicked on the listBox1 to the backing bean?

Comment: When the listener is triggered the value will be set in your "value" attribute of "listBox1", so here in the example the value will be available in the "itemsAvailableSelectOne".

Comment: I guess OP's question is: how do I fill `activityController.subItems` based on the value of `activityController.itemsAvailableSelectOne`? The answer would be: using a proper action in the `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: So I've tried implementing this, but nothing happened when I clicked on anything. What I ended up doing was having to change activityController.itemsAvailableSelectOne to activityController.selected. I'm not sure why, but this caused the event to trigger.